# How do I use the same name for all my environments in anaconda?

Tags: python, anaconda

[screenshot for highlighted text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cMDez.png)

Hi Community,

I am trying to learn the best practice to manage different environments for my data science projects, and I am using anaconda. The screenshot above is from https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html.

In the highlighted text in the picture, how is the author 'using the same name for all his environments'?

Thank you.

Comment: If you have multiple projects, each living in their own directory, and then have a `./envs`  directory in each project, then for each project, you 1) cd to that project's directory, then 2) activate the `./envs` environment. So it's the same name, different location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple projects, each living in its own directory, and then have a `./envs` directory in each project, then for each project, you can

1. cd to that project's directory, then
2. activate the `./envs` environment.

So it's the same name, in a different location for each project.